# Usage cytoscape-popper extension in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, cytoscape.js

I would like to add the tooltip for my graph, but I have a problem with using popper-extension with cytoscape.js. I can't import this extension, because still I receive an error: "Cannot read property 'use' of undefined" when I try to call "use" function. I installed cytoscape and cytoscape-popper using: npm install cytoscape and npm install cytoscape-popper.

Below is part of my code - it's look like in the https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper

```
import cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import popper from 'cytoscape-popper';
cytoscape.use( popper );
```

Do you have any ideas, what I do wrong?

Comment: I'm doing import as you do. But I do `popper(cytoscape);` it seems fine

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

```
import * as cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import * as popper from 'cytoscape-popper';
cytoscape.use( popper );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but in case somebody encounteres this problem again...

In order to not have compilation errors, use the suggested import structure

```
import * as cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import * as popper from 'cytoscape-popper';
cytoscape.use(popper);
```

Later, use the "array notation" to access the popper function registered with cytoscape (https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper):

```
let popper1 = cy.nodes()[0].['popper']({
  content: () => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = 'Popper content';

    document.body.appendChild(div);

    return div;
  },
  popper: {} // my popper options here
});
```